# Write list of lists to text file Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list of lists to write in a text file :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Sample List:

```
[["sample_string_one","sample_string_two","sample_string_three"],["sample_string_four","sample_string_five","sample_string_six"]]
```

Writing to text file:

```
Path sPath = Paths.get("output.txt");
for (ArrayList sampleArr: list){ 
    Files.write(sPath,sampleArr);
 }
```

Error:

The code works, but the error is the contents of the file `output.txt` gets updated.

Expected Contents of `output.txt`:

```
sample_string_one
sample_string_two
sample_string_three
sample_string_four
sample_string_five
sample_string_six
```

Original Contents:

```
sample_string_four
sample_string_five
sample_string_six
```

Essentially, the content of the file gets updated with the latest inner list in the list of lists. Any suggestions to solve this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```java
Files.write(path, list, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

From the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-

> If no options are present then this method works as if the `CREATE`, `TRUNCATE_EXISTING`, and `WRITE` options are present.
>
> `public static final StandardOpenOption TRUNCATE_EXISTING`
> If the file already exists and it is opened for `WRITE` access, **then its length is truncated to 0**. This option is ignored if the file is opened only for `READ` access.

What you want is:

> `public static final StandardOpenOption APPEND`
> If the file is opened for `WRITE` access then **bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.**
> If the file is opened for write access by other programs, then it is file system specific if writing to the end of the file is atomic.